# Need to create a background service that uploads data when internet is available

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I have a personalized feed, with an option for liking comments. When a user hits like button, the app check internet connection, if internet is available api hits gets successful, if internet is down the comment_id is stored in db. I want that when internet resumes, api call should be made with these comment_id.

I Tried broadcast receiver but on changing internet connection broadcast receiver doesn't initialize or wake up.

This is connectivityReceiver code.

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null
            && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();

    Log.d("LLLL",""+isConnected);
   }
}
```

This is my manifest file.

```
<receiver
        android:name=".backgroundServices.ConnectivityReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: That is not a connectivity receiver. It is a broadcast receiver that maybe checks wifi connectivity. But not internet. And further its unclear who sent a broadcast.

Comment: @greenapps can u help me solve the problem statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler#schedule(android.app.job.JobInfo)) for this purpose. Whenever you have pending things to do set the JobScheduler and then it will execute when specified conditions are met. Conditions like

```
 val jobScheduler = getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE) as JobScheduler

        jobScheduler.schedule(JobInfo.Builder(111,
                ComponentName(this, UploadLikesJobService::class.java))
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .setBackoffCriteria(JobInfo.DEFAULT_INITIAL_BACKOFF_MILLIS, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build())
```

This is the `UploadLikesJobService`  class :

```
/**
 * Created by nileshdeokar on 09/02/2018.
 */
class UploadLikesJobService : JobService() {

    override fun onStartJob(jobParameters: JobParameters?): Boolean {
        // Call webservice here and pass the result true or false to jobFinished
        // OS will do the reschedule for you if you pass second parameter true in jobFinished() 
        jobFinished(jobParameters, false)
        return true
    }

    override fun onStopJob(jobParameters: JobParameters?): Boolean {

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the internet you can use this function.

```
public boolean hasInternet() {
ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if (connectivity != null) {
    NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null)
        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
            if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                return true;
            }
}
return false;}
```

This function will return true if internet is working. 
Make a timer to check internet again and again once you get the true from the function perform your connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WorkManager !

> The WorkManager API makes it easy to specify deferrable, asynchronous tasks and when they should run. These APIs let you create a task and hand it off to WorkManager to run immediately or at an appropriate time. For example, an app might need to download new resources from the network from time to time. Using these classes, you can set up a task, choose appropriate circumstances for it to run (like "only while device is charging and online"), and hand it off to WorkManager to run when the conditions are met. The task is still guaranteed to run, even if your app is force-quit or the device is rebooted.
>
> WorkManager is intended for tasks that require a guarantee that the
>   system will run them even if the app exits, like uploading app data to
>   a server. It is not intended for in-process background work that can
>   safely be terminated if the app process goes away; for situations like
>   that, we recommend using

you even can set condition's like if there was networkConnection to work Manager and your task will be executed under that condition

here is the document :

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager#java